# How to get a persistent unique device- or UID in React Native?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, native

I need a persistent and unique device ID or UID within my React Native app for Android and iOS.

I looked into this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-info. Specifically, `getUniqueId()` -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-info#getuniqueid

I read through the notes and there I'm not entirely sure. Firstly, the fact that this function can be seen as critical in certain app stores, which I want to avoid as much as possible.

With iOS, a random string is stored and saved on the device with the help of Keychain. I initially thought that the Keychain disappears with the deletion of the app, but this does not seem to be the case.

So, I could generate a unique UID for iOS, store it using Keychain / https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-keychain, and thus always access the ID, even if the app is deleted and reinstalled. This should remain as long as
A: The device is reset (?), and B: the device is changed

So iOS should be clear here for now. Device switch and device reset doesn't need to be fit in my need.

Is this also possible with `react-keychain` on Android? Because if it is, I could use a unique persistent ID for both devices. This would simplify the development and I wouldn't struggle with the Play Store policies.

Did I overlook something in my research, or are some pieces of information possibly even incorrect?

I need this ID as I want to offer my service without registration but still need a unique user identification.

I appreciate any tips and thank you for reading!